# How to show required message on custom inputs label?

Tags: html, css, validation, message, required

**UPDATE:** I solved the problem by making inputs visible for browser but not for user. Making those changes to CSS worked.

```
.radio-checked {
        opacity:0;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: -1;
}
```

**QUESTION:**

I have custom inputs in my form. I hide them with...

```
display:none;
```

...then styling with css to look different.

Example of my codes:

```
<input id="radio-input" class="radio-check" type="radio" name="odeme">
<label for="radio-input" class="radio-label">Option Name</label>
```

Here is a fiddle for showing how it works.

https://jsfiddle.net/kjaL1zbd/

Problem is, when you hide the input element the validation message is won't show up. You can see example here:

https://jsfiddle.net/kjaL1zbd/1/

So is there any way to show this message on the label? Or is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

```css
/*  RADIO CUSTOM */
form {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}
.radio-check {
 //visibility:collapse;
  margin-left: 22px;
}
.test {
  margin-left: 110px;
}
.radio-label {
 position:absolute;
 padding-left:20px;
 //margin:10px 40px 10px 0px;
 cursor:pointer;
  left:20px;
 }
.radio-label:before {
 content:"";
 display:block;
 width:15px;
 height:15px;
 background-color:#fff;
 border:1px solid #ddd;
 border-radius:100px;
 top:0;
 left:0px;
 position:absolute;
 -webkit-transition:all .2s ease;
 transition:all .2s ease;
 }
.radio-label:hover:before{
 border:1px solid #4198d3;
 }
input[type="radio"]:checked + .radio-label:after {
 content:"";
 width:11px;
 height:11px;
 display:block;
 position:absolute;
 top:3.3px;
 left:3.3px;
 background-color:#4498ff;
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 background-position:center;
 background-size:11px;
  border-radius:100px;
 }
 form{
   margin:50px 0;
   
 }
```

```html
<form>
<input id="ben" class="radio-check" type="radio" name="odeme" required>
<label for="ben" class="radio-label">Option Name</label>
<input type="submit" class="test">
</form>

Click submit button to see the problem. Top is custom, bottom is default.

<form>
<input id="ben" type="radio" name="odeme" required>
<label for="ben" >Option Name</label>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: If i change position to absolute it destroys the design. So i solved it with different solution. Thanks for the idea though.

Comment: Could you give your variant?